# WPF Ribbon - Dock area in Tabs header area

Tags: wpf, ribbon

It is possible insert DockArea or other else docking element like it is on the picture.
In WPF Ribbon.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ribbon [HelpPaneContentTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbon.helppanecontenttemplate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
<ribbon:Ribbon.HelpPaneContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Account: ..." VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <Button Content="Sing out" Click="Button_Click" Margin="2,0,2,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ribbon:Ribbon.HelpPaneContentTemplate>
```

Comment: This is absolutely what I want, thanx.